# php: Database accessing Error

Tags: php, database

I have used "DB.php" package to do the database operation . 
In my file I have connected the database and access the table values. It is working fine. 
when I am running in command line interface .
But When I am running that php file in web browser it telling me following error

**Note :I am Using pgsql database**

```
Can't connect: DB Error: extension not found
```

Comment: What kind of database are you using? It seems you're missing the php module for your specific database.

Comment: What is the "DB.php" package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that its using the same php.ini file for webserver and cli (look at output of phpinfo()).

Once you've established that the php.ini file is correct, if you're still getting the error check the permissions on the extension on the relevant .dll/.so files

If the files and dirs are readable bu the webserver uid, then restart your webserver and check for startup errors.

HTH

C.

Answer (score 0):

Is your php.ini configured for the database that you are trying to connect to?  Are you using MySQL, SQLite ...

http://www.bicubica.com/apache-php-mysql/index.php  There is a section on "Configuring PHP" that would be helpful it sounds like.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to check the script `DB.php`, but it most likely means an extension that's required to communicate with the database such as the [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) or [postgres](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pgsql.php) extensions, is not loaded.

See the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension) on how to load extensions.